# DLP/SLA 3D Printer application [Updated]

Tags: python, web-server, node.js

I want to make a SLA 3d printer with a raspberry pi.
The raspberry must control projector,step-motors,sensors and etc.
The control commands are sent through a touch lcd which is connected to the raspberry.
and also I want to control the printer by a mobile.
I really confused about which is the most compatible language for this?
python or node.js or ...?

Comment: I don't see any Pi specific content in this question.  It would be normal to complete an architectural design before choosing a programming language.  Perhaps if you added your design we could more usefully comment.

Comment: Design has completed.It's just about software and application.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the best" language. Usually more than one are sufficiently suitable for any task. Asking which is best is opinion based at best and leads to flame wars at worst.

Comment: Yes you are right.It's better to ask "which language is more compatible?"